# Hosting app update files on GitHub

Tags: android, database, github, hosting

I have an app which requires its database to be replaced entirely whenever changes are made to the source data. I would like to have this update functionality built into the app, so that the app itself does not need to be updated (ie. re: Play Store), only the database file within it. I am considering hosting/updating the database file (I'm using SQLite) on GitHub for direct download via my application.

The information in the database is not sensitive so I am not worried about security. Additionally, these updates would happen relatively infrequently on a client's device -- 1 to 2 times a year at most.

Bearing in mind I'd like to keep this as free and simple as possible - is this an advisable approach?

Comment: Have you checked Firebase? It's from Google, free and easy to use. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: I guess my question is that, insofar as my GitHub solution works, is there anything wrong with it?

I have in fact worked with Firebase in the past and find it quite useful, in this case I'm just finding it simpler to access files directly from GitHub where they're going to be stored in repositories anyways.